# representing an iteration loop in math

Tags: sequences-and-series, optimization

I have a computation step where

$$
a_{n+1} = f_1(a_n)
$$

That is, $a$ at step $n+1$ is some function $f_1$ of $a$ at step $n$.

I want to iterate till an $N$ where $f_2(a_N) = b$ (where $f_2$ is some other function) 
and then at that $N$ compute  $x = f_1(a_N)$.

Question is how do I write this in a nice compact mathematical formula.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you know that there will be such an $N$ such that $f_2(a_N) = b$, then you can say let $N:= \min\{n \in \mathbb{N} : f_2(a_n) = b\}$. Then saying $x = f_1(a_N)$ makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you've done is just fine. If you want to dress it up, you could write something like

$$
x = f_1(a_H)
$$

where

$$
a_0 = \text{whatever your initial value is}
$$
$$
a_k = f_1(a_{k-1})
$$

and

$$
H = \min \{ k \mid f_2(a_k) = b \}
$$